# Performance optimisation for - MS SQL Delete query with NOT IN caluse

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have following SQL query, and it is taking long time to complete.  I wanted to check if a different query can be used to achieve the same result, but could also help with performance.

```
Delete from table1 WHERE fk_id = '1234' AND pk_id NOT IN ('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc');
```

Note: `pk_id` is `PK` column and `fk_id` is a FK for `table1`.

Comment: how many rows has to delete? And please, accept some answer so more people will want to help you

Comment: Please provide more information.  How big is the table?  Do you have constraints?  Triggers?  Cascading deletes?

Comment: One thing when you ask the questions people do not know anything about your system and tables.Thus while posting try to post as much as possible metadata information about the tables in query. Like size of the table, ddl of table,all the indexes etc.This will make other people to help you much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any suggestions about the query, it's pretty basic.

But you might want to try adding an index:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX (fk_id);
```

Comment: Also, as @Gordon Linoff commented on your question, a delete query is affected by triggers, constraints, and cascading deletes. Those could be what is making it so slow.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you have provided there seems to be no problem with your query as you have used 'AND' condition. Now you need to consider and analyze your database that why is your query taking so much time. So you might want to check out with the following things.

1) select count(1)
from table1
where fk_id = '1234' AND pk_id NOT IN ('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc')
This will give you the count of rows to be deleted.

2) Try something like
  SELECT
    T.name AS TableName
    ,O.name  TriggerName
    FROM sysobjects O
    INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON T.object_id = O.parent_obj
    WHERE O.type = 'TR' AND T.name = 'table1'

This will tell you the triggers associated with your table.

3) You need to further investigate on the table properties for indexes, any constraints present over there.